# Android AssertJ 1.0.0 with Android gradle 1.1.1

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, assertj, android-assertj

Here is part of my `build.gradle` that has conflict:

```
...
dependencies {
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.1'
}
...
testCompile( 'com.squareup.assertj:assertj-android:1.0.0' )
...
```

The issue that I see in log:

```
WARNING: Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations'. Resolved versions for app (21.0.3) and test app (20.0.0) differ.
```

Apparently it removes conflicting dependency from the classpath. I'm not sure if it is `gradle` or `android gradle` plugin.

I've tried next:

```
  testCompile( 'com.squareup.assertj:assertj-android:1.0.0' ) {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
  }
```

But I still have compilation errors so dependency is excluded.

I've tried next:

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {
    // fail eagerly on version conflict (includes transitive dependencies)
    // e.g. multiple different versions of the same dependency (group and name are equal)
    failOnVersionConflict()

    // force certain versions of dependencies (including transitive)
    //  *append new forced modules:
    force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:21.0.3'
    //  *replace existing forced modules with new ones:
    forcedModules = ['com.android.support:support-annotations:21.0.3']
  }
}
```

But looks like it doesn't work since it is not failing on the first conflict and I still have compilation errors.

What will be your suggestions?

*UPDATE* What do I mean by removing dependency - I see a lot of compile errors that `assertj` not found

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran into the same issue.  This fixed it for me:

```
testCompile('com.squareup.assertj:assertj-android:1.0.0'){
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module:'support-annotations'
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I still see a lot `error: package org.assertj.android.api does not exist
import static org.assertj.android.api.Assertions.assertThat;`

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn't work for me. However, adding the following did work for me:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1'
```

and:

```
testCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1'
```

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/29947562/2832027

Comment: The question and answer is already outdated as for me. I don't have any issues in having assertj in the project now. As well AssetJ for Android already went two version up

Comment: The issue still exists as far as the current version of AssertJ (1.1.0) does not use the latest version of support-annotations (23.0.1). The latest versions of Espresso and com.android.support.test:rules also use old versions of support-annotations. I found your question came up when I searched for the error.

Answer (score -2):

You need to change:

```
testCompile( 'com.squareup.assertj:assertj-android:1.0.0' ) {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
```

to:

```
compile('com.squareup.assertj:assertj-android:1.0.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
```

Also ensure that your test folder is called `test` and not `androidTest`

Comment: but compile is used for release versions not test version so release code will have assertj things?