# Can not find ProxyFrameworkImpl by name

Tags: android, mockito, build.gradle, powermock

I work on Android Studio 1.3.1 with gradle 2.2.1.
My app was created on eclipse and then moved to AS. I am making tests using Mockito, PowerMock and JUnit. I got problem with **ProxyFrameworkImpl**, I am sure that my jars contain this class - I found it in the project explorer in section External Libraries.

Log from Debug:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Extension API internal error: org.powermock.api.extension.proxyframework.ProxyFrameworkImpl could not be located in classpath.
at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.registerProxyframework(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:142)
at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.chunkClass(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:173)
at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:92)
at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:85)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:49)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.<init>(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:32)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.<init>(PowerMockRunner.java:34)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidAnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AndroidAnnotatedBuilder.java:51)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at org.junit.runner.Computer.getRunner(Computer.java:40)
at org.junit.runner.Computer$1.runnerForClass(Computer.java:31)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:101)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:87)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.<init>(Suite.java:81)
at org.junit.runner.Computer.getSuite(Computer.java:28)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestRequestBuilder.classes(TestRequestBuilder.java:598)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestRequestBuilder.build(TestRequestBuilder.java:578)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.buildRequest(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:542)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:269)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1837)
```

Dependencies in my gradle.build file consist of jars with powermock, mockito, junit and espresso:

```
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':google-play-services_lib')
    compile('junit:junit:4.12') {
        exclude group: 'org.hamcrest'
        exclude group: 'org.objenesis'
    }
    compile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0') {
        exclude group: 'javax.inject'
        exclude group: 'org.hamcrest'
        exclude group: 'org.junit'
        exclude module: 'junit-dep'
    }
    compile('org.powermock:powermock:1.6.2') {
        exclude group: 'org.objenesis'
        exclude group: 'org.junit'
        exclude group: 'org.hamcrest'
    }
    compile('org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.2') {
        exclude group: 'org.objenesis'
        exclude group: 'org.junit'
        exclude group: 'org.hamcrest'
        exclude module: 'powermock-core'
    }
    compile('cglib:cglib:2.2.2') {
        exclude group: 'org.objenesis'
        exclude group: 'org.junit'
        exclude group: 'org.hamcrest'
    }

    compile('org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.5.5') {
        exclude group: 'org.objenesis'
        exclude group: 'org.junit'
        exclude group: 'org.hamcrest'
    }
```

I have tried to add this class to another jar in the gradle's cache but I got an error like "duplicate dependency".

Comment: Take a look at the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28999124/resolved-versions-for-app-22-0-0-and-test-app-21-0-3-differ/28999596#28999596 - Logging out all project dependencies may show up clashes or version mismatching :)

Comment: did you resole this?