# Espresso Error:Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-v4'. Resolved versions for app (24.2.0) and test app (23.1.1) differ

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso

I have upgraded to the latest API level 24 which is the latest API Level  (at time of writhing) anyhow it caused this error message.

> Error:Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-v4'. Resolved versions for app (24.2.0) and test app (23.1.1) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.

So How can I fix this? 
Also [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28999124/resolved-versions-for-app-22-0-0-and-test-app-21-0-3-differ) the 2nd answer down gives a solution to the problem but if you want to include 
`com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2`
in your then this will lead to 4 more similar error messages.
So How can I get rid of these 4 extra error messages?

Comment: Please, can you show your app **build.gradle** file?

Comment: make sure your gradle dependencies are using the same version

Answer (score 2):

Here are my Espresso build.gradle dependencies:

```
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support:support-annotations:$SUPPORT_VERSION"
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:$ESPRESSO_VERSION"
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:$ESPRESSO_VERSION"
    /**
     * AccessibilityChecks
     * CountingIdlingResource
     * DrawerActions
     * DrawerMatchers
     * PickerActions (Time and Date picker)
     * RecyclerViewActions
     */
    androidTestCompile("com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:$ESPRESSO_VERSION") {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v7'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }
```

where:

```
ESPRESSO_VERSION = '2.2.2'
```

Check my project's `build.gradle` file if you still stuck: https://github.com/piotrek1543/LocalWeather/blob/master/app/build.gradle

Hope it will help

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution (workaround)
If you click on the picture below you will note  look at the picture below  you will note that the error message

> Error:Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-v4'. Resolved versions for app (24.2.0) and test app (23.1.1) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.

will be fixed with the line 
    `configurations.all {resolutionStrategy.force "com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0"}`
Which is located in the dependencies area of the gradle file

 Likewise the error message

> Error:Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7'. Resolved versions for app (24.2.0) and test app (23.1.0) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.

can be fixed with the line
`configurations.all {resolutionStrategy.force "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0"}`
And so on and so fourth until all the errors are solved
p.s Don't forget to go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28999124/resolved-versions-for-app-22-0-0-and-test-app-21-0-3-differ) for the main solution (2nd and 3rd answer down

[image: My Solution]

Answer (score 1):

You can force the support library in your test using:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
```