# Error:Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':app'

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, version

I was trying to solve this gradle error.I imported this project by getting it from a friend of mine.It worked in his system perfectly. Seems like I have a The following issues in my gradle.

Error:Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (27.0.2) and test app (25.4.0) differ.

The following are my gradle

```html
Module app

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.startup.hospital"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.arimorty:floatingsearchview:2.1.1'
    compile 'com.ss.bottomnavigation:bottomnavigation:1.5.2'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:2.0.2'


    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

```html
Project gradle

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.startup.hospital"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.arimorty:floatingsearchview:2.1.1'
    compile 'com.ss.bottomnavigation:bottomnavigation:1.5.2'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:2.0.2'


    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/28999596/2399024

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following in your build.gradle (:app)

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
        force 'com.android.support:support-compat:26.+'
        force 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.+'
        force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.+'
        force 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your espresso has already those dependencies same as you have declared above for support library with different version which is causing problem so exclude theme like below from module **build.gradle** file

```
  androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
```

here is what it should look like

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.startup.hospital"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.arimorty:floatingsearchview:2.1.1'
    compile 'com.ss.bottomnavigation:bottomnavigation:1.5.2'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:2.0.2'


    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
```

and Your project level build.gradle file should not have those dependencies declared again.

Comment: still have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

just added this

```html
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.1.0'
}
```