# Build Error "Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'" when building first default app

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Trying to follow the tutorial here:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project

but after I create an activity and click "Finish" it gives a Gradle build error saying:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'.
```

> Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (26.1.0) and test app (27.1.1) differ. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/test-apk-dependency-conflicts.html for details.

Looking at other SO solutions (the second answer here: [Resolved versions for app (22.0.0) and test app (21.0.3) differ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28999124/resolved-versions-for-app-22-0-0-and-test-app-21-0-3-differ)) it said to add this to the dependencies on build.gradle script:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:xx.x.x'
```

The above solution is also what it shows on Google Samples (https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/blob/ba14ef9e925fa17621bf86abe5336dcb9d53e466/runner/AndroidJunitRunnerSample/app/build.gradle#L36)

So this is now my build.gradle (Module: app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ahmedayman.ember"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0'
}
```

but I'm still getting the same error when I try to sync the project. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

The answer here: [All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification)

mentions that android studio 3.0 replaced `compile` with implementation, so I used `implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'` instead of `compile` (which is mentioned below).

**Original Answer**

The error message provided a link to a website to view. I viewed the website and the website linked to this URL: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips#configure-project-wide-properties

The URL mentioned to configure project-wide properties. It said to add this in my build.gradle project file:

```
// This block encapsulates custom properties and makes them available to all
// modules in the project.
ext {
    // The following are only a few examples of the types of properties you can define.
    compileSdkVersion = 26
    // You can also use this to specify versions for dependencies. Having consistent
    // versions between modules can avoid behavior conflicts.
    supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
    ...
}
```

and to add this in my build.gradle app file:

```
android {
  // Use the following syntax to access properties you define at the project level:
  // rootProject.ext.property_name
  compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
  ...
}
...
dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    ...
}
```

This solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, I did some changes in build.gradle (Module: app) and it worked for me. I changed this

    `androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'`

to:
`androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'`

it worked for me.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution. It might solve the problem for others. What worked for me was following the documentation on the android website. See my answer for more information. (the error message actually provided a link which gave me a simple working solution).

Answer (score 2):

I changed my implementation version for appcompat-v7 to 27.1.1 in build.gradle (Module:app) and it solved the problem for me.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace `jcenter()` with `mavenCentral()` in repositories

Comment: It would be better if you  provided the bit more explanation to the problem and the solution